# Camera Fingerprint - Matlab implementation. Help me run this code

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to run this code, but have reached a dead end due to my inexperience.

http://dde.binghamton.edu/download/camera_fingerprint/

The code is trying to call the Cpp fucntion mdwt in MATLAB, and that gives error. I changed the function call in MATLAB to coder.ceval but that gives the error "Too many output arguments." I would be grateful to anyone who would point out what I am doing wrong in implementing this code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are source code for   [mex functions](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/build-cc-mex-files-1.html), which can be compiled using the [`mex`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html?refresh=true) command. The `compile.m` from the zip file contains the necessary commands to compile the mex files.